# Hosting Emberjs Application on Koajs with koa-static

Tags: node.js, ember.js, koa

I'm hosting an emberjs application on koajs with [koa-static](https://github.com/koajs/static).
according to below code :

```
var app = koa();
var App1 = koa();
App1.use(stati(__dirname + "/App1"));
app.use(mount('/AppViewer',App1));
app.listen(3000);
```

When  calling `localhost:3000/AppViewer` i can't see my page and gets error says can't find .js and .css files, but when calling `localhost:3000/AppViewer/index.html` all things works correctly. so my question is how to see my page when calling `localhost:3000/AppViewer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems strange, because `koa-static` is supposed to default to serving `index.html` on root. Make sure `App1` is not routing the `/` to somewhere else.

Then, you can still get rid of `index.html` in URL by using [`koa-rewrite`](https://github.com/koajs/rewrite). Something like:

```
var rewrite = require('koa-rewrite');
App1.use(rewrite('/*', '/index.html'));
```

**UPDATE**

Tested with the following code:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();
var app1 = koa();
var mount = require('koa-mount');
var serve = require('koa-static');
var rewrite = require('koa-rewrite');
var route = require('koa-route');

app1.use(serve(__dirname + "/app1"));
app1.use(rewrite('/*', '/index.html'));
app.use(mount('/av', app1));

app.use(route.get('/', function *(next) {
  this.body = 'I\'m the main app!';
}));

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: if i use `/app1/` its work but if i use `/app1` it dosent work

Comment: Did you try `App1.use(rewrite('*', '/index.html'));` (no leading slash)?

Comment: Hmm, works for me, with or without trailing slashes. I'll update the answer with the code I used to test.

Comment: Actually, this didn't work for me when using routes with ember-cli.  I found I had to disable the History API (which is what allows you to get arount using #s for routing).  Also, read this: http://www.ember-cli.com/#history-api-and-base-url

Answer (score 2):

This was sufficient for me using ember-cli and deploying to heroku:

```
var common = require('koa-common'),
    koa = require('koa'),
    app = koa();

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    port = process.env.PORT || '3800';

app.use(common.logger());
app.use(common.responseTime());
app.use(common.static(__dirname + "/dist"));

app.listen(port);

console.log('listening on port ' + port);
```

where /dist is the build output for ember build (equivalent of grunt dist w/ EAK)

Answer (score 0):

koa-static didn't work for me. I instead tried koa-static-server and yay!

My middleware:

```
var Proxy = require("koa-proxy");
// const Rewrite = require("koa-rewrite");
const StaticServer = require("koa-static-server");

export const InstallWebApp = (app) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    // Install static web app
    // app.use(Rewrite('/*', '/'));
    app.use(StaticServer({rootDir: `${__dirname}/../../../../client-web/build`, notFoundFile: "index.html"}));
  } else {
    // Install dev server
    app.use(
      Proxy({
        host: `http://localhost:${process.env.WEB_DEV_PORT}`,
      })
    );
  }
};
```